# How to make a excel file that will lock after one year from the date of enterinf password

Tags: passwords

I want to make a excel file that will lock automatically after one year.and there will beca password which can open it for next one year.
Is it possible to make such type of file??

Comment: I'm voting to delete this question because it was asked twice. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/126700/how-to-make-a-excel-file-that-will-lock-after-one-year-from-the-date-of-entering for the other question asked at practically the same time by the same OP.